# How to get full selectors using csstree?

Tags: css, data-structures, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm just learning how to work with CSS ast using csstree: https://github.com/csstree/csstree

I would like to pluck out selectors that I can check agains my HTML DOM and return only those rule sets that match, but I need the full selector:

ex:

```
button.primary.login {...}
```

Currently, I am doing the following:

```
const csstree = require('css-tree');

const ast = csstree.parse(`
  button#primary.red, button#primary.orange { color: "red" }
  div#logo { height: "100px" }
`);

selectors = [];
const collector = (node, current) => {
  if (node.data.type === 'TypeSelector') current = current + node.data.name;
  if (node.data.type === 'IdSelector') current = current + `#${node.data.name}`;
  if (node.data.type === 'ClassSelector')
    current = current + `.${node.data.name}`;

  if (!node.next) return selectors.push(current);

  if (node.next) collector(node.next, current);
};

csstree.walk(ast, node => {
  if (node.type === 'Selector') {
    collector(node.children.head, '');
  }
});

console.log(selectors); // [ 'button#primary.red', 'button#primary.orange', 'div#logo' ]
```

But not sure if this is the best approach. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

**Currently, CSS-tree doesn't have a feature to parse only selected components (*like selector only*).**

but if you need the selector name only, you can improve the performance by disabling a few parsing options:

```js
cssTree.parse(code, {
  parseAtrulePrelude: false,
  parseRulePrelude: false,
  parseValue: false
})
```

By disabling those parsing options, CSS-tree will skip some unnecessary processes, and the compiling process will be more efficient and faster.

---

**references:**

- https://github.com/csstree/csstree/blob/master/docs/parsing.md#parseatruleprelude
- https://github.com/csstree/csstree/blob/master/docs/parsing.md#parseruleprelude
- https://github.com/csstree/csstree/blob/master/docs/parsing.md#parsevalue